# Set-up queue policy not to send expired message to Dead-Letter Queue on Camel endpoint

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a small Camel route which just forward messages to another queue with an expiration time like this:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    defaultOnException();

    // Route all messages generated by system A (in OUTBOUND_A) to system B (INBOUND_B)
    // @formatter:off
    from("activemq:queue:OUTBOUND_A")
        // ASpecificProcessor transform the coming message to another one.
        .processor(new ASpecificProcessor())
        .to("activemq:INBOUND_B?explicitQosEnabled=true&timeToLive={{b.inbound.message.ttl}}");
    // @formatter:on

}
```

I need the messages posted in `INBOUND_B` to be persistent and by default the expired message goes to `ActiveMQ.DLQ` queue after expired.

I know I can modify the ActiveMQ configuration in the `conf/activemq.xml` with

```
<policyEntry queue="INBOUND_B">
 <!-- 
   Tell the dead letter strategy not to process expired messages
   so that they will just be discarded instead of being sent to
   the DLQ 
 -->
 <deadLetterStrategy>
   <sharedDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" />
 </deadLetterStrategy>
</policyEntry>
```

But I would prefer not to change the ActiveMQ configuration (because it needs a restart) and I am wondering if it is possible to send such policy through the Camel endpoint configuration?

Comment: Maybe as a dirty workaround, you can spin up a little route that consumes from your DLQ and then just logs them?

Comment: Not really, because the same kind of message (same body and headers) can be posted in another queue where I really want them to stay in the DLQ. From the DLQ message I cannot see from which queue it expires.

Comment: Carrying on with the dirty workaround, you can actually see where the message has come from and only consume those you see fit. That's called a JMS Selector:
from("activemq:DLQ?selector=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("HEADER='VALUE'","UTF-8")).to("log:discard");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ActiveMQ broker side configuration cannot be updated via the client, that would lead to all sorts of security problems.  You would need to update the broker configuration and possibly not need a restart if you use the [runtime configuration plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/runtime-configuration.html) on the broker.

Comment: Good to know this plugin exists since AMQ 5.9. Is this plugin working well in a master/slave configuration? I'll give it a try.